# increment column one column when another changes

Tags: sql-server

Good Morning, I hope you are well.

I am trying to run a select statement that will cause a column to increment by 1 every time another columns value changes as below:

```
-------------------------------------------
|time                   |routeName|RouteID|
-------------------------------------------
|2015-12-01 00:54:01.000|routeA   |1      |
|2015-12-01 00:54:38.000|routeA   |1      |
|2015-12-01 00:56:18.000|routeA   |1      |
|2015-12-01 00:57:13.000|routeB   |2      |
|2015-12-01 00:57:43.000|routeB   |2      |
|2015-12-01 00:58:18.000|routeC   |3      |
|2015-12-01 00:59:06.000|routeA   |4      |
-------------------------------------------
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If `RouteID` is meant to be the dynamic column where values increase, then you will need another column in you table that will help with ordering the data.

Comment: I see, the source does have a time column I can use to order by,

Comment: Please edit your question and add that `column` with sample data

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
    DECLARE @table TABLE
  (
     routeName VARCHAR(10)
  ) 

 insert into @table values 
('routeA'),  
('routeA'),  
('routeA'),  
('routeB'),  
('routeB'),  
('routeC'),  
('routeA')

SELECT routename,
       Dense_rank()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY routename) AS routeid
FROM   @table
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. 
I tried this solution however the issue is that when the column changes back to 'routeA' the route id reverts to 1

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    id int,
    routeName VARCHAR(10)
) 

 insert into @table values 
(1,'routeA'),  
(2,'routeA'),  
(3,'routeA'),  
(4,'routeB'),  
(5,'routeB'),  
(6,'routeC'),  
(7,'routeA')

SELECT
    t.id,
    t.routename,
    SUM(flag) OVER(ORDER BY t.id)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.routeName,
        IIF(a.routeName = b.routeName, 0, 1) as flag
    FROM @table as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @table as b on a.id = b.id + 1
) as t
```